# Count 2 columns for occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

So basically, I require a query that will return display name, amount of kills and amount of deaths.

I have two tables that I need to pull from.

The two tables are

`player`

```
id      | name
2334324 | user
4353454 | user2
```

where `id` is their unique identifier and `name` is their display name.

The second table is:

`player_kill`

```
id | killer  | victim  |
1  | 2334324 | 4353454 |
2  | 2334324 | 4353454 |  
3  | 4353454 | 2334324 |
```

where `killer` / `victim` columns contain the unique identifier of the `player` table.

I'd like to be able to count the occurrences of player id in the `killer` and `victim` so that the query returns:

```
name | kills | deaths
user | 2     | 1
user2| 1     | 2
```

where the number under kills would be the amount of occurrences the `playerid` has in the `killer` column and same for deaths

Hope I provided enough information.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT `player`.`name`, COUNT(DISTINCT `player_kill`.`id`) as `kills`, COUNT(DISTINCT `player_kill`.`id`) as `deaths`
FROM `player`
LEFT JOIN `player_kill` ON `player`.`id`=`player_kill`.`killer`
LEFT JOIN `player_kill` ON `player`.`id`=`player_kill`.`victim`
WHERE `player`.`id` = `player_kill`.`killer` AND `player`.`id` = `player_kill`.`victim`
GROUP BY `player`.`id`;
```

Comment: And did you try to prepare the query ?

Comment: The furthest i get is name | kills in an individual query, i'm having trouble associating the deaths as well

Comment: fine,but I mean share your code please,because SO do not prepare code for you,but will solve the issue in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
    p.name, 
    count(distinct pk1.id) as kills, 
    count(distinct pk2.id) as deaths
FROM player p
LEFT JOIN player_kill pk1 ON pk1.killer = p.id 
LEFT JOIN player_kill pk2 ON pk2.victim = p.id 
group by p.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/649504/15/0

Comment: Not sure how that works, but that's exactly what I want / needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

See if this works:

```
SELECT  `player`.`name`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT k.`id`) as `kills`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT v.`id`) as `deaths`
    FROM  `player`
    LEFT JOIN  `player_kill` AS k ON `player`.`id` = k.`killer`
    LEFT JOIN  `player_kill` AS v ON `player`.`id` = v.`victim`
    GROUP BY  `player`.`id`;
```

If not, then we may need to make the COUNTs into subqueries.

Comment: this works too :) still not sure what these queries are doing though, thanks for your help :D

Comment: @Dewanta was faster on the draw.  The two solutions are equivalent if `player`.`id` and `name` are 1:1.  We both added "aliases" to get past the ambiguity of having two `player_kill` references.